# using #each in handlebars not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a var with products and if I console log it out it shows this.

```
Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  mongooseCollection: 
   NativeCollection {
     collection: null,
     opts: { bufferCommands: true, capped: false },
     name: 'products',
     collectionName: 'products',
     conn: 
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: null,
        port: null,
        user: null,
        pass: null,
        name: null,
        options: null,
        otherDbs: [],
        _readyState: 0,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: false,
        _listening: false },
     queue: [],
     buffer: true,
     emitter: 
      EventEmitter {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined } },
  model: 
   { [Function: model]
     hooks: Kareem { _pres: {}, _posts: {} },
     base: 
      Mongoose {
        connections: [Object],
        plugins: [],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object] },
     modelName: 'Product',
     model: [Function: model],
     db: 
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: null,
        port: null,
        user: null,
        pass: null,
        name: null,
        options: null,
        otherDbs: [],
        _readyState: 0,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: false,
        _listening: false },
     discriminators: undefined,
     schema: 
      Schema {
        obj: [Object],
        paths: [Object],
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        singleNestedPaths: {},
        nested: {},
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [Object],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: {},
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        _requiredpaths: undefined,
        discriminatorMapping: undefined,
        _indexedpaths: undefined,
        query: {},
        childSchemas: [],
        s: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        '$globalPluginsApplied': true },
     collection: 
      NativeCollection {
        collection: null,
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'products',
        collectionName: 'products',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: true,
        emitter: [Object] },
     Query: { [Function] base: [Object] },
     '$__insertMany': [Function],
     insertMany: [Function] },
  schema: 
   Schema {
     obj: 
      { imagePath: [Object],
        title: [Object],
        description: [Object],
        price: [Object] },
     paths: 
      { imagePath: [Object],
        title: [Object],
        description: [Object],
        price: [Object],
        _id: [Object],
        __v: [Object] },
     subpaths: {},
     virtuals: { id: [Object] },
     singleNestedPaths: {},
     nested: {},
     inherits: {},
     callQueue: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     _indexes: [],
     methods: {},
     statics: {},
     tree: 
      { imagePath: [Object],
        title: [Object],
        description: [Object],
        price: [Object],
        _id: [Object],
        id: [Object],
        __v: [Function: Number] },
     _requiredpaths: undefined,
     discriminatorMapping: undefined,
     _indexedpaths: undefined,
     query: {},
     childSchemas: [],
     s: { hooks: [Object], kareemHooks: [Object] },
     options: 
      { retainKeyOrder: false,
        typeKey: 'type',
        id: true,
        noVirtualId: false,
        _id: true,
        noId: false,
        validateBeforeSave: true,
        read: null,
        shardKey: null,
        autoIndex: null,
        minimize: true,
        discriminatorKey: '__t',
        versionKey: '__v',
        capped: false,
        bufferCommands: true,
        strict: true,
        pluralization: true },
     '$globalPluginsApplied': true },
  op: 'find',
  options: { retainKeyOrder: false },
  _conditions: {},
  _fields: undefined,
  _update: undefined,
  _path: undefined,
  _distinct: undefined,
  _collection: 
   NodeCollection {
     collection: 
      NativeCollection {
        collection: null,
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'products',
        collectionName: 'products',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: true,
        emitter: [Object] },
     collectionName: 'products' },
  _traceFunction: undefined,
  _castError: null,
  _count: [Function],
  _execUpdate: [Function],
  _find: [Function],
  _findOne: [Function],
  _findOneAndRemove: [Function],
  _findOneAndUpdate: [Function] }
```

I am trying to use `#each` to get the products and show lets say the title first.

Here is my method in index js using node

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Product = require('../models/product');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    Product.find({}, function (err, products) {
        // check for and handle query errors
        if (err) {
            console.error('Product.find() error', err);
            return next(err);
        }

        // continue to render the view with `products` available
        console.log(products);
        res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping Cart', products: products });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here is the foreach sentence at index.hbs

```
{{#each products}}
    <p>{{products.price}}</p>
    {{/each}}
```

I tried different ways like `#each this` and then getting it but non seem working.

Just incase if needed when I search in the db

```
> db.products.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5855c55482d8722419e21a7d"), "imagePath" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/5/5e/Gothiccover.png/250px-Gothiccover.png", "title" : "weeee", "description" : " AWeeesomeee", "price" : "15", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5855c55482d8722419e21a7e"), "imagePath" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/5/5e/Gothiccover.png/250px-Gothiccover.png", "title" : "Gowwww", "description" : " this is great", "price" : "15", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5855c55482d8722419e21a7f"), "imagePath" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/5/5e/Gothiccover.png/250px-Gothiccover.png", "title" : "killaa crw", "description" : " i love it", "price" : "15", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5855c55482d8722419e21a80"), "imagePath" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/5/5e/Gothiccover.png/250px-Gothiccover.png", "title" : "joker", "description" : " kill em", "price" : "15", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5855c55482d8722419e21a81"), "imagePath" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/5/5e/Gothiccover.png/250px-Gothiccover.png", "title" : "harley", "description" : " naughtttyyy", "price" : "15", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5855c55482d8722419e21a82"), "imagePath" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/5/5e/Gothiccover.png/250px-Gothiccover.png", "title" : "suicide", "description" : " squad", "price" : "15", "__v" : 0 }
> db.products.count()
6
```

App.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

app.connect('localhost:27017/shopping');

// view engine setup
app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({defaultLayout : 'layout', extname: '.hbs' }));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: ahh okay.. so like it should have a function(err, result){
var = result;
}
Something like this?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski
I tried it, but the page came empty :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose' [`model.find()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find) doesn't return the results directly as Mongo's command-line does.

```
var products = Product.find();
```

It expects a callback function to be provided either to it directly, following the `conditions`, or provided to a method of the [`Query` object](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js) it returns:

```
function proceedWithProducts(err, products) {
    if (err) {
        // handler query error
    } else {
        // use products
    }
}

// a couple options...
Product.find({}, proceedWithProducts);
Product.find().exec(proceedWithProducts);
```

Within the route:

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    Product.find({}, function (err, products) {
        // check for and handle query errors
        if (err) {
            console.error('Product.find() error', err);
            return next(err);
        }

        // continue to render the view with `products` available
        console.log(products);
        res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping Cart', products: products });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey Jonathan, thanks for the code, but after taking this codes and restarting the server, my local host got stuck, I restarted both node js and mongo db , but for some reason its not working anymore...

Comment: Not getting anything on the console.log too

Comment: Sorry. What do you mean by it being "stuck?" Are any errors being logged?

Comment: There is no error...just not even loading the page.

Comment: I've revised the snippet's error handling to log the `err`. Does using that provide any additional details?

Comment: Just restarted the sever, and mongodb, but the page is literally unresponsive. It looks like adding Product.find for some reason makes it unresponsive, when I just used var product = Product.find then it was alright.

Comment: @MasnadNihit Realized you're using Mongoose. Without calling that out, I'd assumed you were using [MongoDB's own Node.js Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/). For Mongoose, the `Model`'s `.find()` method always expects the 1st argument to be the `conditions`. Try adding `{}` as an argument before the callback.

Comment: The same problem occured again, even with the new codes, I will post the whole index.js and app.js file just incase if needed.

Comment: I added more files to my question, so you can see the whole case now... I am still having the same issue...

Comment: Thanks for all the help!! I found my mistake!!! I forgot to connect the app to mongoose! I am sorry for all the trouble. But I did learn alot from you.